# Python decorators in C#, what's a good alternative?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, decorator, python-decorators

I'm working on a C# console app based on Banking. It has a few regular methods in my `Account` class such as:

- CheckBalance
- DepositMoney
- GetMoney

And I want there to be a 3-tries PIN mechanism in each one of those.

Now, I could just write that mechanism in one of them and copy paste it, but that's bad practice.

I recalled that python has a very convenient tool called `decorators`, they decorate the function below and can inject code before/after the method. I actually was able to recreate decorators in C#, but here they're... much more clunky. Another issue is that I cannot create a single decorator for `Func<T1>`, `Func<T1, T2>`, `Func<T1, T2, T3>`... and so on. I have to create a separate decorator for each such case (not to mention that T1 wouldn't even work for some reason, C# complains about the types and I have to use `int`, `string`, etc.).

I found some packages on nuget and they'd definitely make it easier. However I also found out that this pattern is closely related to AOP (aspect-oriented programming) and I heard that it's not recommended for bigger projects, since it's harder to debug and understand what's actually going on.

That's why I'm looking for different patterns to achieve the same goal. Is there some other technique that'd allow me to achieve this functionality?

Comment: I don't know decorators of Python, but why don't you simply call that functions (those in place of decorators) from within the methods?

Comment: For this case that'd probably work, but for my other bigger project I want to create something that'd insert the same code in a more complicated way. Like the main contents of the method would be nested within the if/else/try/catch from the decorator.

Comment: For simpler cases, you might be looking at [Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/reflection-and-attributes/attribute-tutorial) and for more complex you might be interested in libraries for aspect orientation. But I'd actually recommend you post a [mcve] of the problem you have, maybe we can solve it more simple.

Comment: This sounds like delegates/actions, lambda expressions....but tbh I don't really know what the goal is here. Passing in delegates to methods are great, but there are also a number of cases where code could be substantially clearer and more maintainable by doing it a more "vanilla" OOP approach. You really should post an example of what you intend here. I've seen very unreasonable abuse of delegates...Its not fun